# Converting from day-of-year to month-day in C

Tags: c, date

This is probably a FAQ, but I couldn't find anything.

My company tracks the date and time in Julian and Zulu; for example, 2014-224-17:20:00Z

I would like to write a little converter to print the date and time in EST/EDT.

Unfortunately, the `mktime()` function will not do this automatically.  According to the man page,

```
The [mktime] function  ignores
the  values  supplied  by the caller in the tm_wday and tm_yday fields.
```

So I can apparently convert 11-aug-2014 into Julian day 223, but I cannot easily go from day 223 to a date.

Can somebody point me the way to figure out, given year 2014 and day-of-year 223, what the date is?  Or is "manually" my only option?

Comment: manual it is. a binary search will bring it back pretty quick.

Comment: To clarify, **Zulu** (time) I _assume_ you mean [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)  (aka Coordinated Universal Time). UTC is the correct (formal) or recommended name for the time zone. Also "Greenwich Mean Time" is not _necessarily_ (in sub-second definition) synonymous, so please don't use it when you mean UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have date and time as strings, you can use [strptime()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html):

```
 char s[] = "2014-224-17:20:00";
 struct tm tm;

 strptime( s, "%Y-%j-%H:%M:%S", &tm );
```